# golang-migrate no change error on initial migration

Tags: go, golang-migrate

I'm using `golang-migrate` for managing migrations everything seems to work correctly when running tests on `github actions` CI, but I can't make it work when running on docker image. I just keep getting a `no change` error. Connection to database is established and `.sql` migrations work as well. Any suggestions on how could I debug what's actually going on?

```
func runMigrations(databaseUrl string) {
    m, err := migrate.New(
        "file://migrations/",
        databaseUrl,
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error loading migrations: %v", err)
    }

    if err := m.Up(); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error migrating Up: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably you need to add a check `err != migrate.ErrNoChange` to your code. In this case, "migrate" is the name of the package

https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/issues/100